# Symmetric bilinear forms over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, with a symmetric bilinear form $(\cdot, \cdot)$.

It is well known that if Char$F\neq 2$, then there is a basis $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ of $V$ w.r.t. which the matrix $[a_{ij}]=[(v_i,v_j)]$ is diagonal.

This fact is not necessarily true in Char$F=2$.

> **Q.** Although, in Char$F=2$, the matrix $[a_{ij}]=[(v_i,v_j)]$ is not diagonal, how much can be its simplest form?

This question may be thought from following known fact: given a linear transformation $T$ from $V$ to $V$, and $F$ algebraically closed; then with some basis of $V$, the matrix of $T$ is not diagonal, but it is *almost diagonal*-Jordan form.

Similarly, although, the matrix of a bilinear form is not linear, how much simple form we can expect of it?

Comment: http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-39

Comment: I have this book; what is exact place you want to state?

Comment: He does forms over characteristic 2 fields. Chapters 12, 13, 14, mostly 12. The general view, that of Witt, is done in a fairly concrete way in Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms, but probably not the adjustments to char 2.